# Return to Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have no experience at Ubuntu or any other Linux OS. Yesterday I tried to upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 10 and some problems occurred. I couldn't install Windows 10 and I even lost my Windows 7 data. I figured out the problem was my Windows 10 .iso file. I hadn't any access to another computer and I had only Ubuntu DVD, so I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04. After I installed Ubuntu I made a Windows 10 installer USB.

Then the problems began. I connected the USB and nothing happened, also After I installed Ubuntu, I lost access to regular blue screen BIOS settings. When I see the "Click F2 for BIOS" option, it doesn't matter how fast I click or how many times I click, the PC automatically boots Ubuntu. I started to think how to solve my problem and I found a stupid idea. I have few hard drives at my house, so I thought if I change the hard drive of the notebook, I could install a new Windows to  a new hard drive.

When I changed the hard drive, my notebook keeps resetting every second. I thought the hard drive may be broken, so I tried 5 different hard drives, but the result was same for all of them. The only hard drive that let me boot the notebook is the one on which Ubuntu is installed.

I gave up trying, and I went to several computer service centers at my district. Each one of them gave advice that contradicted the others and said I had a different (expensive) problem. The first one said: "You deleted your BIOS, I can repair it, but it will cost about $100. The second one said: "It's a common issue, your motherboard is broken. We have to change your motherboard and it will cost maybe $150+." The third one said: "I can't fix this." Someone even said that the CPU is toast. If the CPU is toast, how is it possible that I can run Ubuntu on a notebook with this CPU in it?

I couldn't find someone who could fix this or help me.

I just want to return back to Windows. I'm not a pro PC user. I'm a basic man with basic interests. I searched this BIOS issue at forums, etc., but all the answers are different from each other, and I couldn't find someone who fixed this issue. My last hope is here. *How can I remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?*

I'm trying to install windows 10 but im keep getting this error
https://lnv.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/77304i6A597C124E80E9D9/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

my notebook is Samsung NP300e5c. When I run `lspci -v` I get the following results:

```
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])

Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NP300E5C series laptop
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
I/O ports at 3088 [size=8]
I/O ports at 3094 [size=4]
I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
I/O ports at 3090 [size=4]
I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
Memory at 90608000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
```

I tried to find driver for Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller and I downloaded from Microsoft website https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=dae354e4-426c-4766-9261-06650f361f79
and unpacked the .cab file to another USB stick, but the Windows installer is not able to locate this driver. When I try to find the hard drive at the Windows installer screen (see below screenshot), it doesn't see the hard drive either.

[image: Windows installer screen]

I'm sure it's possible to install Windows 10 on this PC, because I used Windows 10 on it a few months ago.

Comment: First download the Windows 10 installation ISO from Microsoft then, in Ubuntu, use MKUSB to burn it to a USB stick (minimum 8GB): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive (scroll up the page for MKUSB installation instructions). If you have access to a Windows computer then it's preferable to use the official Media Creation tool, the default offer when you download the same ISO from a Windows system. >>>

Comment: >>> Then to boot from it, if F2 (or ESC or DEL) don' t work, try removing the HDD/SSD. If nothing else works this should give you access to BIOS/UEFI (UEFI in your case, likely).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, i bought windows 10 bootable flash drive, windows 7 booatable flash drive and windows 10 dvd but i coudnt boot any of them. I also tried to power on the notebook without hdd but notebook keep restarting after i click power button.

Comment: What happens when you press `shift + f10` during the Installation window that you have posted at last of your questions...?

Answer (score 0):

ext4 is the default filesystem format in Ubuntu 18.04, but Windows is expecting a hard drive that is formatted as NTFS. Otherwise the Windows installer will stop and not continue, because it does not recognize your laptop's ext4 formatted hard drive. To solve this problem boot the laptop from the live DVD/USB that you used to install Ubuntu 18.04. You may need to set the USB flash drive as first in the boot sequence in the BIOS, so your laptop will be able to boot from it. Open the built-in GParted partition editor application, and format the entire hard drive as NTFS.

If this doesn't work then buy a portable hard drive enclosure. They are very cheap, being just a box the same size as a laptop's 2.5" hard drive with a USB port and a USB cable to attach it to another computer. Remove the laptop's hard drive and plug it into the portable hard drive enclosure. Then take the portable hard drive enclosure to another computer and format the hard drive as NTFS. After the hard drive is formatted as NTFS, put it back in its original place in the laptop.

[image: portable hard drive enclosure]
<sup>**portable hard drive enclosure**</sup>

Now your laptop is ready to install Windows. When you boot the Windows 10 installer after formatting the laptop's hard drive as NTFS, the Windows installer will recognize it and the Windows 10 installation will proceed normally.

Comment: i have ubuntu installer flash drive but i coudnt boot from it , notebook keep opening with installed ubuntu at hdd

Comment: You need to press the Del key or whatever key you need to press to access the BIOS setup utility, and set the USB drive to be first in the boot sequence. I wrote this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority/1084586#1084586) about how to do it.

Comment: i feel really stupid person but i cant access bios either. I can send a video about it if you want to see, i dont know is it important thing or reason but i might activated uefi settings at bios when i have acces to bios.

Comment: GParted also has a bootable live USB that runs entirely from RAM. This GParted live USB is super lightweight and will often boot successfully even if no Linux distro is able to boot on that computer.

Comment: finally i made a little progress , now my pc can see windows 10 installer flash drive and boot from it (looks like it doesnt find any hdd connected to pc https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/attachments/hard-disk-not-detected-3-jpg.23262/)

Comment: If the hard drive was formatted as NTFS maybe the Windows 10 installer would find it.